# Can I Upgrade shimono Ultegra 9 speed 12-27 cassette

Tags: cassette, derailleur-rear, compatibility, upgrades

I have a 2009 Trek 7.7 FX with Ultegra 12-27T cassette, 50/39/30 Front triple. I want to upgrade the rear cassette to give better hill climbing gears. Can I fit an 11-34 Rear cassette and if so what else needs to change?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your rear derailleur. For 11-34 you will need a long cage one.

Comment: A triple probably has a long cage derailleur already which has a stated tooth capacity of 40. Your system has (50-30)+(27-12)=35. If you put 11-32 at the rear it would be 41 which might work.